# Very basic HTML5 Canvas code failing to run. Is this me or my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to learn to use HTML5 Canvas for a project, and just started using an online tutorial (a beautifully written one actually, here is the link: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html).  However as soon as I started to replicate it, it is not working.  My browser is the latest release of Chrome, JavaScript is on, etc.  I am working in Visual Studio, but this is also failing to work on JSFiddle and my simple text editor.

Here is what is in the body of the HTML file:

```
<canvas id="c" height="500" width="375"></canvas>


<script src="CanvasTest.js"></script>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domloaded, false);
function domloaded() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();

    // Draw vertical lines
    for (var x = .5; x < 500; x += 10) {
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, 375);
    }

    // Draw horizontal lines
    for (let y = .5; y < 375; y += 10) {
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(500, y);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = "#00000";
    context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: I just saw that. And I got the height and width mixed up.  Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) feature `let`, change that to `var`.

Here's an example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/rifazarari/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

You put `let` instead of `var` in your for `loop`.